# Create failed for Job 'SSIS Package Exec'

Tags: sql-server, ssis, job-scheduling, sql-server-2008, sql-agent-job

I created an SSIS package entitled **"DimEntity.dtsx"**

I followed the instructions from this link to run this SSIS package using a scheduled Job.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/23/sql-server-running-ssis-package-in-scheduled-job/

After following the process of **running-ssis-package-in-scheduled-job**, I got this error after clicking OK from the image below.

[image]

Create failed for Job 'SSIS Package Exec'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'owner_sid', table 'msdb.dbo.sysjobs'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 515)

---

Could someone help me resolve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select General on the left tab and enter a value for owner.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the owner manually:

```
update msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view 
set owner_sid=suser_sid('<username or groupname here>',0) 
where name = 'jobname'
```

Comment: This is also correct and it worked for me. Both answers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The job owner was probably set to [sa] by hand whereas it needs to be sa (or it is when set by the "Browse" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a vpn to access your server but you are not part of the domain, it may put your local machine's domain in and then fail.  This is what happened to me.  I browsed for an owner and selected one from the server's domain and this fixed it.